# How do i use ArcGIS Maps in Angular-Js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

How do i use ArcGIS Maps in Angular-Js easily with manipulating the;

- zoom
- locate
- adding markers
- search my places by Geo coordinates and Place name
- loading markers lazily and the like?

Can some one Give me a sample please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a very simple way of adding all the mentioned features and be able to control them in this way.

```
 angular.module('eBlood').directive('esriPointRenderersMap', ['$q', 'appConfig', 'esriLoader', 'esriRegistry', function($q, appConfig, esriLoader, esriRegistry) {
    return {
        // element only directive
        restict: 'E',

        // isolate the scope
        scope: {
            // 1-way string binding
            rendererActive: '@',
            // 2-way object binding
            basemapActive: '=',
            clusterTolerance: '=',
            heatmapRendererParams: '='
        },

        compile: function($element, $attrs) {
            // remove the id attribute from the main element
            $element.removeAttr('id');
            // append a new div inside this element, this is where we will create our map
            $element.append('<div id=' + $attrs.id + '></div>');
            // since we are using compile we need to return our linker function
            // the 'link' function handles how our directive responds to changes in $scope
            // jshint unused: false
            return function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {};
        },

        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var mapDeferred = $q.defer();
            var esriApp = {};

            // add this map to the registry
            if ($attrs.registerAs) {
                var deregister = esriRegistry._register($attrs.registerAs, mapDeferred.promise);
                // remove this from the registry when the scope is destroyed
                $scope.$on('$destroy', deregister);
            }

            esriApp.createGeoCordFinder = coords => {
                return esriLoader.require([
                    'esri/geometry/Point',
                    'esri/tasks/Locator'
                ]).then(x => {
                    var Point = x[0];
                    if (!esriApp.mapLocator) {
                        var Locator = x[1];
                        esriApp.mapLocator = new Locator('https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer');
                    }
                    return esriApp.mapLocator.locationToAddress(new Point(coords)).then(res => {
                        return res.address.Match_addr;
                    });
                });
            };


            esriApp.zoomToLocation = mapOptions => {
                if (mapOptions.view) {
                    mapOptions.zoom = mapOptions.zoom || appConfig.pointRenderers.mapOptions.zoom;
                    mapOptions.view.goTo({
                        target: [mapOptions.coordinates.longitude, mapOptions.coordinates.latitude],
                        zoom: mapOptions.zoom
                    });

                    // change the marker to the current Geo.
                    var promise = (!mapOptions.address) ? esriApp.createGeoCordFinder(mapOptions.coordinates) : $q.when(mapOptions.address);

                    promise.then(location => {
                        esriApp.changeLocationMarker({
                            view: mapOptions.view,
                            attributes: {
                                address: location
                            },
                            geometry: {
                                longitude: mapOptions.coordinates.longitude,
                                latitude: mapOptions.coordinates.latitude
                            }
                        });
                    });

                }
            };


            esriApp.createLocateIcon = mapOptions => {
                var container;

                if (!mapOptions || !mapOptions.view)
                    return $q.reject('Our MapView is setYet');

                container = mapOptions.container |"map";

                mapOptions.container = undefined;
                mapOptions.goToLocationEnabled = appConfig.goToLocationEnabled;
                mapOptions.graphic = null;

                return esriLoader.require([
                    'esri/widgets/Locate'
                ]).then(x => {

                    var Locate = x[0];
                    esriApp.locateWidget = new Locate(mapOptions, container);
                    esriApp.locateWidget.startup();

                    if (!container)
                        mapOptions.view.ui.add(esriApp.locateWidget, 'top-left');

                    esriApp.locateWidget.on('locate', data => {
                        esriApp.zoomToLocation({
                            view: mapOptions.view,
                            coordinates: data.position.coords
                        });
                    });

                    return esriApp.locateWidget;
                });

            };

            function setSearchWidget(opts) {
                var srcNodeRef;

                if (!opts || !opts.view) {
                    return $q.reject('MapView is undefined');
                }



                srcNodeRef = opts.container;

                opts.container = undefined;
                opts.showPopupOnSelect = false;
                opts.autoSelect = false;

                return esriLoader.require([
                    'esri/widgets/Search'
                ]).then(x => {
                    var Search = x[0];

                    var searchWidget = new Search(opts, srcNodeRef);
                    searchWidget.startup();

                    if (!srcNodeRef) {
                        opts.view.ui.add(searchWidget, 'top-right');
                    }

                    searchWidget.on('search-complete', e => {
                        if (e.results.length > 0 && e.results[0].results.length > 0) {
                            var res = e.results[0].results[0];
                            var coords = {
                                longitude: res.feature.geometry.longitude,
                                latitude: res.feature.geometry.latitude
                            };

                            esriApp.zoomToLocation({
                                view: opts.view,
                                coordinates: coords,
                                address: res.name
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    return searchWidget;

                });
            }


            var mapoption = {
                map: esriApp.map,
                container: 'map',
                zoom: 3,
                padding: {
                    top: 65
                },
                view: esriApp.mapView
            };



            esriApp.buildmap = (mapViewDiv) => {
                return esriApp.creatMap({
                    basemap: $scope.basemapActive
                })
                    .then(map => {
                        mapoption.map = map;
                        mapoption.container = mapViewDiv;
                        return esriApp.createMapView(mapoption);
                    });
            };

            esriApp.creatMap = properties => {
                return esriLoader.require(['esri/Map'])
                    .then(esriModules => {
                        var Map = esriModules[0];
                        return new Map(properties);
                    });
            };

            esriApp.createMapView = config => {
                return esriLoader.require(['esri/views/MapView'])
                    .then(x => {
                        var MapView = x[0];
                        esriApp.mapView = new MapView(config);
                        mapDeferred.resolve({
                            view: esriApp.mapView
                        });
                        return mapDeferred.promise;
                    });
            };

            esriApp.map = esriApp.buildmap($attrs.id);


            mapoption.view = esriApp.mapView;
            esriApp.createLocateIcon(mapoption);
            setSearchWidget(mapoption);


            mapDeferred.promise.then(function(esriApp) {

                // clean up
                $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                    esriApp.map.destroy();
                });
            });
            // });




        }
    };
}]);
```

The simple directive will be very use full. More so now that it updates the 'appConfig' global config object with the map features. This worked very well for me.

Thanks Guys for you contributions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Below is the sample to load ArcGIS/ESRI map using angular-js and for more details and relevance sample/concept [read getting-started](https://github.com/Esri/angular-esri-map#getting-started) from below mentioned link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="esri-map-example">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">

        <title>Angular Esri Quick Start</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/css/main.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body, .esri-view {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MapController as vm">
        <esri-scene-view map="vm.map" view-options="{scale: 50000000, center: [-101.17, 21.78]}">
        </esri-scene-view>

        <!-- load Esri JSAPI -->
        <script src="//js.arcgis.com/4.0/"></script>
        <!-- load AngularJS -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
        <!-- load angular-esri-map -->
        <script src="//unpkg.com/angular-esri-map@2"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            angular.module('esri-map-example', ['esri.map'])
                .controller('MapController', function(esriLoader) {
                    var self = this;
                    esriLoader.require(['esri/Map'], function(Map) {
                        self.map = new Map({
                            basemap: 'streets'
                        });
                    });
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

More more details [please click here...](https://github.com/Esri/angular-esri-map)

Hoping this will help you to understand and start your implementation :)

Answer (score 1):

This website has many examples and sample code:
http://esri.github.io/angular-esri-map/#/home